# Website with php 7.3 fpm running into 503 Service Unavailable after 24h

Tags: php

We are currently working on a small web app and we ran into an issue. The error keeps occuring and we got kind of stuck.

```
503 service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request.
```

**What we use:**

- PHP 7.3 fpm mode
- apache2
- VMWare, Machine with debian 9, 2cpu/2cores and 16gb RAM

We currently have about 70 users on the website. After about 24h the server keeps crashing.

after restarting the php service the website works again. So I'm guessing the issue has something to do with php and not with apache.

according to other sources this issue might be caused because of opcache or max sessions / max child config.

**www.conf:**

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 12
pm.min_spare_servers = 8
pm.max_spare_servers = 24
pm.max_requests = 1000
```

**php.ini:** https://pastebin.com/JanEHinF

any ideas what could cause the error?

Comment: keep `mysqli.reconnect = On` , it could be the issue

Comment: Thank you @Gulshan for your reply. Could this work? as for the app, we are actually only connecting via API on a different server where the Database connection is managed.

Comment: Install sar and record memory and cpu usage, this way you can see what happens just before the crash, does it crashes always in the same clock time? It may be a job?

Comment: That quoted error - is that just what you see in the frontend, or from the error logs?